# Auto post facebook in php

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Following code for auto post on Facebook, but it shows me an `OAuthException`.

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$page_info = $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");

try {
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api(
        '/PAGE_ID/feed', 
        'POST',
        array (
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'message' => 'This is a test',
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token']
        )
    );
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream'
    ));
    print_r($e->getType());
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Tried accessing
>   nonexisting     field (access_token) on node type (User) thrown in
>   /home/malwatal/public_html/basic/lib/base_facebook.php on line 1028

Comment: .. And your question is?

Comment: how can i solved it

Comment: `$page_info['access_token']` doesn't exist

Comment: It is not that easy to post to facebook from an php application. You need to register as a developer, set up an app, get the access_token for a specific site, You can only access from the site you specified, you can not test it from a local testenvironment. At least that's my last experience with fb api, already 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's time to use facebook v5 sdk

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app_id',
  'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
  ]);
             // facebook auto post

$params = array(
  "message" => "$title in $merchant   $short",
  "link" => "http://pickmyoffers.com/",
  "picture" => "http://Pickmyoffers.com/images/searched/Flipkart.png",
  "name" => "www.Pickmyoffers.com",
  "caption" => "www.pickmyoffers.com",
  "description" => "Submit Coupon and earn money through Pickmyoffers.com | Deals,Coupons and offers."
);
            $post = $fb->post('/Page_id/feed',$params, $access_token);
            $post = $post->getGraphNode()->asArray();

}
```

hope it's help